# Convert From ASCII W/O chr() Python

Tags: python, pygame, ascii, chr

I am writing a program to get keyboard inputs. Here is the code:

```py
key = 0
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        for key in keys:
            if event.key == key:
                key = key
                if key != None:
                    print(key)
                    print(chr(key))
                    return chr(key)
                else:
                    return
```

The problem is that the key is too large in `ASCII` for `chr()` to handle. For example, when I press <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, it spits me an error. What I am trying to do is get the integer of the `pygame.keydown` and convert it to an `ASCII` character, then return that character. Is there any way, besides `chr()`, that won't give me the error?

```py
ValueError: chr() arg not in range(0x110000)
```

Comment: Not every key is going to correspond to a character - what do you think `caps lock` should return?  Better to just work with the integer values.

Comment: `key = key` doesn't make any sense in that context. Also, the `for` loop seems unnecessary when you can simply use `if key in keys`.

Comment: If the key event does represent a printable character, that character will already be in `event.unicode` - no conversion required.

Answer (score 1):

A user friendly name of a key can be get by [`pygame.key.name()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.name):

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

        print(pygame.key.name(event.key))
```